# Stochastic differential equation with constant drift and linear diffusion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm new to Itô calculus and currently examining a process with the dynamics:
$$
dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma X_t dB_t,\quad 0\leq t\leq T < \infty, \quad X_0 = x
$$
where $\{B_t, t\geq 0\}$ is a standard 1-dimensional Brownian motion. The task of the current exercise is to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_T^2]$, any ideas on how to approach this?

I have tried defining a new process $Y_t=X_t^2$ and using Itô's formula but it doesn't seem to get my anywhere. Thankful for all input!

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck when you apply Itô's formula?

Comment: Applying Itô's formula with the suggested transformation yields:
$$
 dY_t = (2\mu X_t + \sigma^2 Y_t)dt + 2\sigma Y_t dB_t,
$$
which to me doesn't seem like an easier thing to deal with

Comment: Well, what happens if you take the expectation?

Comment: @saz Is there a better way to go than the one in my answer?

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Not really. In order to avoid the $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$-term in the ODE you can consider $\mathbb{E}((X_t-\mathbb{E}(X_t))$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$...

Comment: @Saz okey! I just wondered if there was a trick to somehow avoid solving any ODE’s, but maybe there isnt.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen I see. Well, the solution to the SDE can be expilcitly and using the expliticit formula you can certainly compute $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$ ... but from my point of view this is not easier than applying Itô's formula and solving the ODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that your notation
$$
dX_t = \mu dt + \sigma X_t dB_t
$$
is just a shorthand for
$$
X_t=X_0 + \int_0^t \mu ds + \int_0^t\sigma X_sdB_s.
$$
Now after applying Itô's lemma (which you have done correctly) you get
$$
dX_t^2=(2\mu X_t+ \sigma^2 X_t^2)dt+2 \sigma X_t^2 dB_t.
$$
Now taking the expectation you get
\begin{align}
E[X_t^2]& =  E[X_0^2+ \int_0^t 2\mu X_s + \sigma^2 X_s ds+ \int_0^t 2 \sigma X_s^2 dB_s] \\
& = E[X_0^2]+2 \mu \int_0^t E[X_s]ds+ \sigma^2 \int_0^t  E[X_s^2]ds + 0 \\
& = X_0^2 + 2 \mu \int_0^t E[X_s]ds+ \sigma^2 \int_0^t  E[X_s^2]ds
\end{align}
where we used linearity of expectation, Fubini's theorem (to change the order of expectation and the integral) and the fact that the expectation of stochastic integral is zero.

Now this can be written as
$$
\frac{d}{dt} E[X_t^2] =  2 \mu  E[X_t]+ \sigma^2   E[X_t^2] = 2 \mu X_0+2\mu^2 t +\sigma^2E[X_t^2].
$$
This is because $E[X_t]=X_0+\mu t$. Solving this linear ODE gives you the solution.

Comment: That works!! Thank you :)